# Use one or multiple random number generators for genetic algorithms?

Tags: java, random, genetic-algorithm

I'm implementing a genetic algorithm using Java programming language. As you know, there are some random events in the algorithm like roullete selection, crossover, mutation, etc. In order to generate a better probability distribution among these events, which approach should be better, to use a unique Random object or create a separate Random object for each event?

Answer (score 3):

Use a single object. Random number generators are designed to have long periods -- using the same seeded instance, you get a good sequence of random digits out. If you're constantly creating and destroying them, you're only getting however much randomness there is in the seeding process, which may even be none. Imagine what happens if your RNG is seeded from the system clock, and you're doing it thousands of times per second, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a single Random stored globally, and refer to it everywhere you need randomness. What's more, initialize it with a known seed, and write this seed to a file along with the results of the genetic algorithm.

In addition to the benefits mentioned by deong, this lets you rerun the whole program exactly if you find some interesting outputs. It can be extremely frustrating with genetic algorithms to see an interesting result and then be unable to reproduce it, because it was a rare outcome. If you have the seed, you can just rerun the program deterministically.

If you want each run to use a new seed you can do it like this:

```
long seed = new Random().nextLong();
log("Seed for the current run is: " + seed);
Global.setRandom(new Random(seed));
```

That way you get a new random seed everytime, but you can still reconstruct a given run if you need to.

Note that the Random object should not be shared between two different runs. At the start of each run, you should create a new random object and make a note of the seed.

Comment: However, if you need (for some reason) to run the algorithm multiple times and you want it to run in parallel (each run independently but several runs at once), you need separate RNG for each run. But regarding a single run of GA, single RNG is the best option.

Comment: @Gandalv Actually, that's something I should have clarified. Each run should have it's own fresh Random object. If you share the object between runs, they are no longer deterministic.